Wrong path language from windows search API
I have the following code to search the windows index for specific files. As a result I get a list of files with the filename and the path.
The problem is that I have a German system and the path the search returns is in German format. For example: I get "C:\Benutzer" instead of "C:\Users" as my path. So the path is not language independent.
I then want to use the path to open the explorer at the location I got from the search. But when I launch the explorer with the German path as an argument it always opens the Documents folder.
So is there any way to always get an English path from the search:
Here my code:
var connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Search.CollatorDSO;Extended Properties=""Application=Windows""");

try
{
    connection.Open();
    var query = $"SELECT TOP 5 System.ItemName, System.ItemPathDisplay FROM SystemIndex WHERE scope ='file:' AND System.ItemName LIKE '%{searchFile}%'";

    var command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);

    var searchedFilesView = new SearchedFilesView();
    content = searchedFilesView;

    List<(string name, string path)> files = new List<(string name, string path)>();

    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string fileName = reader["System.ItemName"].ToString();
            string filePath = reader["System.ItemPathDisplay"].ToString();

            files.Add((fileName, (filePath)));
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
    return false;
}
finally
{
    connection.Close();
}


Every property that contains the term "Display" in its name is localized. System.ItemName doesn't and it's the real file system name. In theory we should be able to use System.ParsingPath but it's not exposed like this, so you can use path instead of System.ItemPathDisplay (it will have a URI format, ie: file://...). Other shortcurts are filename, write, access, create, attrib.

To address the issue of language-dependent paths in your search results, you can consider using the System.ItemUrl property instead of System.ItemPathDisplay. The System.ItemUrl property provides a URL that should be language-independent and can be used to open the file location in Windows Explorer.
Here’s how you can modify your code to use System.ItemUrl:
var connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Search.CollatorDSO;Extended Properties=""Application=Windows""");
try
{
    connection.Open();
    var query = $"SELECT TOP 5 System.ItemName, System.ItemUrl FROM SystemIndex WHERE scope ='file:' AND System.ItemName LIKE '%{searchFile}%'";
    var command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);
    var searchedFilesView = new SearchedFilesView();
    content = searchedFilesView;
    List<(string name, string url)> files = new List<(string name, string url)>();
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string fileName = reader["System.ItemName"].ToString();
            string fileUrl = reader["System.ItemUrl"].ToString();
            files.Add((fileName, fileUrl));
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
    return false;
}
finally
{
    connection.Close();
}


